# Switching multiple motors on after some delay

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT) #forward
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT) #forward
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)  #backward
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT) #backward
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT) #Motor


print ("Car is moving Forward.")

GPIO.output(16, 1)
GPIO.output(26, 1)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(5, 0)
GPIO.output(6, 0)

time.sleep(4)





print ("Sprinkling Water.")
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(16, 0)
GPIO.output(26, 0)
GPIO.output(5, 0)
GPIO.output(6, 0)


time.sleep(2)


print("Car is moving backward.")
GPIO.output(5,1)
GPIO.output(6, 1)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(16, 0)
GPIO.output(26, 0)

time.sleep(3)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Now I want is that my car moves forward, stops and then sprinkles water and then moves backward. But, with this code..My car is moving forward while sprinkling water and then stopes while the sprinkling motor is on and then backward while the motor is on (the motor never stops).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT) #forward
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT) #forward
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)  #backward
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT) #backward
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT) #Motor


print ("Car is moving Forward.")

GPIO.output(16, 1)
GPIO.output(26, 1)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(5, 0)
GPIO.output(6, 0)

time.sleep(4)

    print ("Stopping the motors.")
    GPIO.output(16, 0)
    GPIO.output(26, 0)
    GPIO.output(5, 0)
    GPIO.output(6, 0)

    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW) #turn on pump
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH) #turn off pump

    print("Car is moving backward.")
    GPIO.output(5,1)
    GPIO.output(6, 1)
    GPIO.output(16, 0)
    GPIO.output(26, 0)
```

Comment: It didn't work, brother. I just did the same....my sprinkling water motor never stops. Just to clear,  this (sprinkling water) motor is being controlled through relay and one of the wire is going in the digital pin which is being low.

Comment: I am assuming that the relay is controlled by pin25? Is this correct? Does the relay click?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: You did not answer my question if the relay clicks. These 3 lines GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW) #turn on pump
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH) #turn off pump should turn the pump on for 1 seconf then off. You can try changing low to high and vice cersa, but you say that the relay is active low. Also, how do you have the relay connected to the pump?

Comment: Your given piece of code worked brother. Thanks a lot. <3

Comment: If you look close that is the same code I posted before.

Comment: you there? 
My code isn't working although everything is fine. My motor is not switching off while my tires are moving. 
Can you help? Should I post the code?

Comment: @spiCkyyy adding to an old question is not likely to be seen by many people. I suggest you open a new question and definitely include your code.